# GitLab CI/CD pipeline error while installing npm packages [package.json file not found]

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have the gitlab repository setup with the frontend and backend folders inside it. Basically my folder structure is as below,

```
--repo
 - frontend folder
 - backend folder
 - gitlab-ci.yml
```

According to the docs, the gitlab-ci.yml file is placed in the root folder as provided in the image.

I am getting the error while running the pipeline. "npm install" command does not gets executed, instead it gets errored out as no such file or directory. The package.json file is placed inside the backend folder.

I would require to change the directory while npm install command and also to deploy.

My gitlab-ci.yml file is as below,

```
# Node docker image on which this would be run
image: node:8.10.0

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - test
  - deploy_production

# Job 1:
Test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install

# Job 2:
# Deploy to staging
Production:
  image: ruby:latest
  only:
    - master
  stage: deploy_production
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=XXXXXXX --api-key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`npm install` needs to run in a folder containing a `package.json` file. I suspect this file might be present in your subfolders (`frontend` and/or `backend`).
You should add

```
  before_script:
    - cd backend # or frontend
```

to your `Test` job.